# Using RetroPie with Nvidia Shield Gamepad only allows for certain buttons

Tags: drivers, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B running the latest version of RetroPie. I would like to use the controller from the Nvidia Shield. After attempting to change the controls, I noticed that only certain keys on the controller appeared to work. Those keys were:

- Power
- Back
- Play
- Home
- Volume Up, Volume Down

The controller works normally, I have no problems with using keyboard controls, and I have the latest drivers.

How can I correct the problem?